# Switching Activities from menu: return to main activity starts it over

Tags: android, android-activity

Short problem description: starting new activity at menu seems to lead to multiple main activities (at least via 'Back' navigation), and I can not find a "standard" way to navigate Activities.

Details:
I am writing a really small, simple and straight forward app with one main activity and two "sub" activities, namely `show` and `settings`. Both sub activities are declared with    `android:parentActivityName="mainActivity"`. In the menu I want to let the user switch between those activities.

I have read the android developer tutorial to create a menu, this tutorial stops at `newGame()` and `showHelp()` in `onOptionsItemSelected`. Other tutorials led to the following:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected! " + item.getItemId());
    Intent intent;
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.settingItem:
        intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
```

...

Of course the main activity should be also included in this menu, but I also want the "Up" and "Back" to be working as usual.

So my question is which style is androidish? The main activity is quite expensive in creating, since it uses Camera and Camerapreview.

1. Destroy the mainActivity with finish() everytime a 'settings' or 'show' is called, and create it again on 'Back', 'Up' and 'main activity' events?
2. Write three different menus or onOptionsItemSelected for the main activity (which does nothing when 'main activity' is chosen) and each sub activity?
3. Save the Intent for the main activity and try to reuse this?

If there already is some tutorial out there (for a API level >= 11) defining the simple switching between the apps, I really would like to read it. But I'm quite lost in all I have found now.

Comment: use custom popup menu in actionbar

Comment: short and fast hint, but "custom popup menu" does not say anything about how to activate/start the chosen one of the three activities.